# Windows command works from command prompt but not in cmd file. Any idea why?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to run the following command from a batch file (I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523365/execute-sql-server-scripts/3523459#3523459)), but it doesn't seem to work. Yet when I run it from a cmd window, it runs fine.

Can anyone explain why, and more importantly, what I can do about it?

The command is;

```
for %f in ("../Schema Objects/Schemas/dbo/Programmability/Stored Procedures/*.sql") do echo %f
```

The error I get when it's run from a batch file is;

> f was unexpected at this time.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The %f in your batch file needs to be %%f.