# Run a query from a file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I don't have permission to execute xp_cmdshell procedure.

Is there anyway I could execute a query from different file?

I tried this and don't know if it is a good option:

```
 --query1.sql
 Create Procedure sp_1
 as
 Begin
    declare @q1 varchar(MAX)
    set @q1 = ' some complicated query '
    exec(@q1)
 End


 --query2.sql
 Create Procedure sp_2
 as
 Begin
    declare @q1 varchar(MAX)
    set @q1 = ' some complicated query '
    exec(@q1)
 End

 --mainquery.sql
 Exec sp_1
 Exec sp_2
```

Any advice?

Comment: My advice is to explain what kind of trouble you have and also explain where there is any relation to the `sp_cmd` procedure which you are not allowed to execute.

Comment: @alzaimar - [Execute a text file from SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241925/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-text-file-from-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have `BULK INSERT` permission you could try to import the file using the `BULK INSERT` command, construct the query from the imported 'table' (which should consist of exactly one column), combine the contents into one `varchar` varialbe and then execute it.

```
create table #tmp (cmd varchar (255))
bulk insert #tmp from 'd:\foo.txt'
declare @cmd varchar(max), @row varchar(255)

declare x cursor for select cmd from #tmp
open x

set @cmd=''
fetch next from x into @row
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
  set @cmd = @cmd + @row
  fetch next from x into @row
end
close x
deallocate x
exec (@cmd)
```

But it requires you to have `BULK INSERT` permission.