# TSQL call query from wtihin a query in same database

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am blaming this on Monday morning, but is there some way to run a query from within a query.....

Isn't there some sort of command like

```
EXEC sp_ myOtherQuery.sql
```

I realize this lacks all sorts of error handling just wondering if there was some way to do this.

Comment: there's `EXEC <stored-procedure-name> <parameters>`  -- miss off the `.sql`.

Comment: Its not an SP though, the SP_ was a call to the default procedures that might be able to call the query to run like sp_rename when renaming tables.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My eyes missed the space. SQL generally doesn't like working with files directly.

Comment: SQL as a product does not really interact with .sql files.  That is just how SSMS saves the files.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it easy to do or recommended? No. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241925/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-text-file-from-sql-query

Comment: Why is it not recommended? This is not a text file, it is native SQL to the same DB. No parameters will be passed. Just some processing and table copies created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar situation and used something like:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
declare @spname nvarchar(256)
set @spname=<your_database_name> + '.dbo.' + 'sp_executesql'
set @cmd='your query text'
execute @spname @cmd
```

Comment: So I can only call a SP? Well okay I think I see this let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in SQL Server Management Studio:

Turn on `SQLCMD` mode using the query menu. Then use the `:r` directive to include the other sql file into the one you're editing.

```
--sql statements
:r "C:\Full\Path\To\Sql\File.sql"
--More sql statements
```

This is effectively an include directive. The contents of the sql file will be inserted in your script at run time and the whole thing will be run as one.

This works only in SSMS. It isn't something you can do in a stored procedure.