# How to remove GO from variable so it could be executed by sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find a T-SQL way to remove GO command from scripts which I read from .sql files. I'm using similar to this approach [Execute SQL scripts from file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57572931/1606233), which suits my needs very well, however some of the files contains GO command and breaks execution as `sp_executesql` doesn't handle non T-SQL commands.
How to create a `REPLACE` which would remove GO, which mostly sits alone in the row? Or any other method I could apply here? Please keep in mind, that in the script there could be other GOs, which are actually not a command.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) = 
    'DECLARE @table AS TABLE(
        [Id] INT,
        [Info] NVARCHAR(100)
        );

    INSERT INTO @table
        ([Id],[Info])
    VALUES
        (1,''Info''),
        (2,''Show must go on''),
        (3,''GO'');

    SELECT * FROM @table;

    GO';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Using `xp_cmdshell` to execute scripts is not an option due to server security restrictions. `SQLCMD` is not an option too this time.

Comment: I think the real problem is that you're trying to use `sys.sp_executesql` as a replacement for something like `sqlcmd`. Removing the `GO`s could easily be a breaking change.

Comment: Trying to differentiate between string literals and reserved keywords is a tough nut that's going to rely on an awful lot of text parsing. What's the feasibility of editing your script files outside of SQL Server?

Comment: As another nail in the coffin, T-SQL is a terrible language for string manipulation. You would need to parse the batches, and then remove the `GO`s where appropriate. Honestly, that's an impossible task for the language.

Comment: If you need to execute a script with GO batch terminators programmatically, consider using the SMO API per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814/execute-a-large-sql-script-with-go-commands). T-SQL isn't the right tool to parse scripts.

Comment: How are you getting the command from your file into a T-SQL variable?

Comment: You could pick up a [TSQL parser](https://github.com/bruce-dunwiddie/tsql-parser) and modify it to handle SQLCMD commands. That ought to be a reliable way to remove the offending `GO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would NOT claim that this is the way this *should* be done, but it was some fun to ticker it down:

Disclaimer: This is a demonstration why TSQL is the wrong tool for this

I added some more GO-separated statements and used quotes within to get it even more tricky:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) = 
    'DECLARE @table AS TABLE(
        [Id] INT,
        [Info] NVARCHAR(100)
        );

    INSERT INTO @table
        ([Id],[Info])
    VALUES
        (1,''Info''),
        (2,''Show must go on''),
        (3,''This includes a GO and some "quoted" text''),
        (4,''GO'');

    SELECT * FROM @table;

    GO

    SELECT TOP 10  * FROM sys.objects
    GO
    PRINT ''Each GO will be used to have separate patches''';
```

--let's start by removing various kinds of line breaks

```
SET @sql = REPLACE(REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@sql,'json'),'\r','\n'),'\n\n','\n');
```

--Using a `CS_AS`-collation will avoid to take "go" as we (hopefully!) can rely on "GO":

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =  CONCAT('["',REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'GO' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'","GO'),'\n','","'),'"]');
```

--Above I used each upper-case "GO" **and** each line break to separate the string.
--Doing so we transform your string into a json array
--Now we can fill this into a table using `OPENJSON` to read the json-array (ommitting empty lines)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(RowIndex INT IDENTITY,fragment NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @tbl(fragment)
SELECT STRING_ESCAPE(A.[value],'json') 
FROM OPENJSON(@json) A
WHERE LEN(TRIM(A.[value]))>0 AND TRIM(A.[value])!=NCHAR(9);
```

--We need these variable for the cursor

```
DECLARE @patch NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

--Now I open a cursor
--We do this by running down a *recursive CTE* once again building up a json array.
--This time we will separate the strings when the upper-case "GO" is sitting alone in its line.

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT RowIndex, CAST(CONCAT('["',fragment) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) growingString  
    FROM @tbl WHERE RowIndex=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n.RowIndex
          ,CONCAT(cte.growingString,CASE WHEN TRIM(n.fragment) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS=N'GO' THEN N'","' ELSE n.fragment END)
    FROM @tbl n 
    INNER JOIN cte ON n.RowIndex=cte.RowIndex+1  
)
,thePatches AS
(
SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(growingString,'"]') AS jsonArray 
FROM cte ORDER BY RowIndex DESC
)
SELECT A.[value] AS patch
FROM thePatches p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(p.jsonArray) A;
```

--we can - finally - walk down the patches and execute them one by one

```
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @patch;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    PRINT @patch; --PRINT out for visual control before execution!
    --EXEC(@patch);
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @patch;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

There are millions of things (e.g. line-breaks within content, commented sections, *max recursion*) which can destroy this approach. So clearly DO NOT follow this suggestion :-)

Comment: Neat but (as you acknowledge) brittle, e.g. `GO 10` is going to be a common thing in such deployment scripts, and that will either break this or eliminate the loop, I didn't test. As you and others have suggested, T-SQL just isn't the place to do this. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand of course! you are right  This was more sort of fun and a way to demonstrate why this should **not** be done with TSQL